# Testing default operations in C++

Tags: c++

I would like to write unit-tests for the six 'default operations' related to an object's lifecycle in C++. I am referring to the following:

1. Default constructor: `A()`
2. Copy constructor: `A(const A&)`
3. Copy-assignment operator: `A& operator=(const A&)`
4. Move constructor: `A(A&&)`
5. Move-assignment operator: `A& operator=(A&&)`
6. Destructor: `~A()`

I am building a library and would like to ensure that all classes that implement the above work consistently as per [C22 of the C++ Core Guidlines](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rc-matched); my primary concern is consistent copying/assignment behaviour. My library uses classes from external libraries, written in older versions of C++, which I suspect may not feature all of the above. Nevertheless I'd like to tease out how they behave when subjected to a suite of tests designed to test the default operations above. That will (hopefully) help me make class behaviour consistent throughout the library.

Are there a few standard test-cases that I can implement to help me test the above? Is this a dumb idea in the first place?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What information do you intended to glean from these catchall tests? What would a default constructor test test for? How would it know it was right?

Comment: I guess tests of the default constructor and destructor wouldn't really make sense. What I had in mind for a copy constructor was something like: creating a copy, changing a member, then testing the values of the original and copy's member for equality. The outcome would be different if the copy was a deep copy vs. a shallow copy. I suspect there are other things I should be testing too, especially since I'm not too familiar with when exactly the move functions are called. I could of course just do it all myself, but was hoping someone had done the hard work already!

Comment: The problem is every class is different and behaves differently. Even your small example doesn't hold for classes using shared resources. 
Ultimately you'd have to write each test yourself specifically for each class. As a side note, its not recommended to have tests just for 3rd party code. You should focus on writing tests for your code to ensure your library works properly regardless of what 3rd party libraries you use in the implementation.

Comment: Primary problem is that you have to modify `a` to check if method are consistent. you probably also need `operator ==` (and `operator !=`).

Comment: You might enforce your custom rules with static analyzer (as clang tidy) (so implementation of `operator !=` is `{ return !(*this == rhs); }`, swap idiom used to force coherency)...

Comment: Thanks. Of course you are right about shared resources vu1p3n0x, I don't think I need to manage any fortunately. I understand that I'll need custom code for each class. I suppose it's probably more effort than it's worth. I now think it would be better just to do a few tests to deduce the 3rd party classes' behaviour, then make my own classes behave similarly (i.e. adopt a policy that's not backed by tests).

Comment: Thanks Jarod42. I'll look into clang tidy/static analyzers.